# Querying a subset

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write an SQL query to find records which contain a particular column and from that subset want to find records which doesn't contain a some other value. How do you write a query for that?

```
cid  id2  attribute
--------------------------------
 1  100  delete 
 1  100  payment
 1  100  void
 2  100  delete
 2  102  payment
 2  102  void
 3  102  delete
 3  103  payment
```

In above example, I want to list cid for which payment and delete attributes exist but void attribute doesn't exist. So it should list out 3 from above example because it doesn't have void attribute.

Forgot to mention that there could be more attributes. However, I need to list out records for which delete and payment exist regardless of other attributes but void doesn’t.

Comment: Always put the name of dbms you are using as well along with your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call this a "set-within-sets" query, because you are looking for particular sets of attributes within each `cid`.

I would express this with `group by` and conditions in the `having`:

```
select cid
from t
group by cid
having sum(case when attribute = 'payment' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when attribute = 'delete' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when attribute = 'void' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

In some databases, you can simplify this with string aggregation -- assuming there are no duplicate attributes for `cid`s.  For instance, using the MySQL function:

```
select cid
from t
where attribute in ('payment', 'delete' 'void')
group by cid
having group_concat(attribute order by attribute) = 'delete,payment';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select cid
from tablename
where attribute in ('delete', 'payment', 'void')
group by cid
having
  count(distinct attribute) = 2
  and  
  sum(
    case attribute 
      when 'void' then 1
      else 0
    end 
  ) = 0
```

If there are not more attributes than these 3, then you can omit the `WHERE` clause.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j1QmwJMx2RSYJrzMvpNjx7/3).
Results:

```
| cid |
| --- |
| 3   |
```

Comment: What if there are more than 3 attributes? Will this query still work? I have updated the question.

Comment: It will work, try it. If there where only 3, then you could omit `where attribute in ('delete', 'payment', 'void')`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there are only three attributes, so the logic behind this query is:

First `COUNT` the number of attributes `GROUP BY` cid, and then `LEFT JOIN`  the original table `ON` attribute is *void*. You should grab cid that has exactly 2 attributes and no *void*.

The original table is named as `temp`:

```
SELECT
    subq2.result_cid
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
      SELECT
          T.cid AS result_cid,
          COUNT(T.attribute) AS count
      FROM
          temp AS T
      GROUP BY
          T.cid
    ) AS subq
    LEFT OUTER JOIN temp AS T2 ON subq.result_cid = T2.cid AND T2.attribute = 'void'
) AS subq2
WHERE subq2.count = 2 AND subq2.id2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There could be more attributes. I have updated the question.

Answer (score -3):

use corelated subquery by using `not exists`

```
     select t1.* from tablename t1
     where not exists( select 1 from tablename t2 
                 where t1.cid=t2.cid and attribute='void'

                 ) 
                 and exists ( select 1 from tablename t2 
                               where t1.cid=t2.cid
                             having count(distinct attribute)=2
                            )
                            and attribute in ('payment','delete')
```

[demo online](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j1QmwJMx2RSYJrzMvpNjx7/2)